# Update Classroom courseState using patch

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I am trying to write an Apps Script function to archive a whole bunch of courses in Google Classroom.

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = Classroom.Courses.list();
  var optionalArgs = {'courseState': 'ARCHIVED'};

  var courses = response.courses;
  if (courses && courses.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
      var course = courses[i];

      Classroom.Courses.update(course.name, course.id, {'updateMask':'courseState'}, body=optionalArgs); // Line 10
      //Logger.log('%s (%s) [%s]', course.name, course.id, course.enrollmentCode);
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error when running the above code:

> Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 2-3 only (line 10, file "ArchiveAll")

What is the correct way of doing this with Google Apps Script and the `Classroom` advanced service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code, it looks like you may have previously used the Python client libraries (specifically the `body=optionalArgs` portion). In JavaScript / Google Apps Script, keyword parameter assignment isn't a thing, at least not like it is in Python.

The [format expected by class methods in Google's "Advanced Services" client libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#how_method_signatures_are_determined) are derived from the HTTP REST API specification for the associated API. For the `Classroom.Courses.update` call, this is [`courses#update`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/update) (or per your title, [`courses#patch`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/patch)).

The REST API spec for `update` is for 1 path parameter (the course id), and a request body with a `Course` resource. As with all Google APIs, you can additionally add any of the [Standard Query Parameters](https://developers.google.com/classroom/query-params) as an optional argument. This count - 2 required, 1 optional) corresponds with the error message you received:

> Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 2-3 only

Thus, your function should be something like:

```
function updateCourse_(course) {
  course.courseState = 'ARCHIVED';
  const options = {
    fields: "id,name,courseState" // data sent back in the response.
  };
  return Classroom.Courses.update(course, course.id, options);
}
```

The `patch` method has an additional optional argument, the `updateMask` query parameter. As with other optional parameters (like Standard Query Parameters), this is passed in an object as the last parameter to the class method:

```
function patchCourse_(courseId) {
  const newMetaData = {
    courseState: 'ARCHIVED',
    // other options, must be valid Course fields per patch documentation:
    // https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/patch#query-parameters
  };
  const options = {
    updateMask: "courseState", // CSV string of things you alter in the metadata object 
    fields: "id,name,courseState" // data sent back in the response
  };
  return Classroom.Courses.patch(newMetaData, courseId, options);
}
```

The `updateMask` allows you to use some template `Course` resource and only apply the specified portions of it to a specified course. If you were to use `update` instead of `patch`, you would alter all fields to use the template's values:

```
function patchedViaTemplate_(templateCourse, courseId, fieldsToAlter) {
  const options = { updateMask: fieldsToAlter };
  return Classroom.Courses.patch(templateCourse, courseId, options);
}
```